# Minimize, Maximize, Close buttons gets hidden under top panel

Tags: 14.04, eog

I did ubuntu 14.04 clean install (Run into some problems but this is the one I want to share)

So When I open long letter box images (Eog) I get eog menu under ubuntu top panel.

Here is a video you can look at

I noticed other software get this issue as well Like chrome if it has to open a pop-up that it gets the same issue

http://www.mediafire.com/view/8r9fum00qrkip5o/eog%20problem.ogv

So can anyone help me with this small but massively annoying issue

Thank You for your time

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me as well. It's quite annoying and I don't have a perfect solution although here is what worked for me.

Press `win_logo + w` choose that particular window and press and hold `alt` and move the window until you can see the buttons.